# While True Loop stops ruuning

Tags: python, while-loop

Im trying to validate a simple question, does the user want to play a game - Yes or No.

```
while True:
    start = ''
    start = input("Do you want to play Python Black Jack? Enter Yes or No: ")

    if start.lower().startswith('y'):
        print("let the game begin")
        break

    elif start.lower().startswith('n'):
        print ("Goobye")
        break

    else:
        print ("Looks like you did not enter a valid answer!")
        continue
```

The code does run correctly couple of times but then it suddenly stops running - What I think happens is that when I break the while loop the True Statement does not apply any more, hence when I re run the program it does not enter the while loop again.

Could you please help let me know what im doing wrong or what is happening or what is the best practice to avoid this filing loops.

Comment: Please reproduce your actual indentation. What you have posted will not run.

Comment: `break` specifically means "stop the loop". you probably want another loop, where this is just the beginning part of it..

Comment: When you break the loop, you are NO LONGER inside the loop so I am not sure what you are expecting. Give more clearance and indent your code please. Thanks!

Comment: The code is in fact correctly indented - when I copy pasted it , the indentation got removed. 

How ever the issue is : that the code does in fact run properly couple of times, then it suddenly just stops working. I have to restart the kernel & then it begins prompting the information again & re running the code, but then it just stops.

Comment: @JuanRodriguez What kernel? Are you saying you need to restart your operating system?

Comment: Im using jupyter lab Alpha - so it has the option to restart the kernel - and each time I restarted it everything worked correctly.

But all good now it worked

Answer (score 0):

The **break** statement will break out of the loop. If any of the conditions executing *break* are True at some point, then your loop will stop.

Comment: I think `break` stopping the loop is the intended behaviour (after all it'd makes no sense to keep asking for an answer after a valid answer has already been entered). I think what the OP is saying that after he breaks out of the loop, the loop can't be entered again. Of course there's nothing in the code that would try to enter the loop again (i.e. no outer loop or the like), so there's clearly information missing here. Really, it's just a badly asked question.

Comment: @sepp2k You understood his question well. Indeed he just needed another loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want two loops - one to keep the game running, one to get a yes/no answer.. Maybe structure your code like this:

```
def shouldStartGame():
    while True:
        start = input("Do you want to play Python Black Jack? Enter Yes or No: ")

        if start.lower().startswith('y'):
            print("let the game begin")
            return True

        if start.lower().startswith('n'):
            print ("Goodbye")
            return False

        print ("Looks like you did not enter a valid answer!")

while True:
    if not shouldStartGame():
        break

    print("Here the rest of the game goes")
```